# Is phpThumb still a good solution?

Tags: php, image, libraries, phpthumb

A long time ago I used a PHP library called phpThumb to show different sizes of my images on my website.

Today I need to do the same. Googling phpThumb gave me 2 results:

- http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/
- http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/

Are they the same?

Should I stick to phpThumb, or is there a better library today?

Comment: I've never heard of `phpThumb` but I've heard of [`ImageMagick`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

Answer (score 3):

They don't look the same to me, but the latter link definitely appears to be newer than the former (they are different version numbers, and the former was last updated in August 2011) so if I were to pick one to use now, I would go with http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/.

Unfortunately I'm not aware of any other thumbnail generating libraries for PHP. I have always just generated thumbnails using [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).

Answer (score 1):

Most people just using ImageMagick (convert). I'm also using phpThumb as it covers most behaviors you want to do with images. In background it is using ImageMagick (if available). The library has a cache functionallity and you can output the image to string to build your own cache (e. g. memcache for very frequently used images).

I think its still the best php library for image conversion and resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Personally speaking, I still use phpThumb. The CMS-system I usually use (Modx) has a built-in Extra for it, and as far as I can see, it still works like a charm, even though it's a bit old.

phpThumb (the Sourceforge one) was a EXCELLENT library when it first came out, and it is still very powerful. I don't know about any other libraries for PHP that has the same level of customizations and optimization, especially for caching.

I'd recommend sticking to the library for now, unless you have a good reason not to. You could also try to google around for `php thumbnail library` but you'll most likely have to dig deep to find anything as good as phpThumb.

By the way, for the others out there, phpThumb uses ImageMagic-functions a lot to do it's compressions.

Comment: Right, my main reason for phpThumb is the caching feature...

Comment: I would just stick to phpThumb if you already are familiar with the api and function-calling. Caching is a big plus that you don't get from using only ImageMagick.